# How to match Rust's `if` expressions in a macro?

Tags: macros, rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to write a macro that will rewrite certain Rust control flow, but I'm having difficulty matching an `if` expression. The problem is that the predicate is an expression, but an `expr` is not permitted to be followed by a `block` or `{`.

The best I've got is to use `tt`:

```
macro_rules! branch {
    (
        if $pred:tt 
            $r1:block
        else
            $r2:block
    ) => {
        if $pred { 
            $r1
        } else {
            $r2
        }
    };
}
```

Which works fine with single-token or grouped predicates:

```
branch! {
    if (foo == bar) {
        1
    } else {
        2
    }
}
```

But fails if the predicate was not grouped:

```
branch! {
    if foo == bar {
        1
    } else {
        2
    }
}
```

```
error: no rules expected the token `==`
```

I also tried to use a repeating pattern of `tt` in the predicate:

```
macro_rules! branch {
    (
        if $($pred:tt)+
            $r1:block
        else
            $r2:block
    ) => {
        if $($pred)+ { 
            $r1
        } else {
            $r2
        }
    };
}
```

But this produces an error because it's now ambiguous whether subsequent block should match the `tt` too:

```
error: local ambiguity: multiple parsing options: built-in NTs tt ('pred') or block ('r1').
```

Is there a way to do this, or am I stuck with inventing special syntax to use in the macro?

Comment: I do not want to be negative, but macros are such a mess… I also failed to match some of the Rust constructs.

Comment: @Boiethios I remember. I will just have to invent special syntax, similar to what you probably had to do with your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a [TT muncher](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-incremental-tt-munchers.html) to parse the predicate:

```
macro_rules! branch {
    {
        if $($rest:tt)*
    } => {
        branch_parser! {
            predicate = ()
            rest = ($($rest)*)
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! branch_parser {
    {
        predicate = ($($predicate:tt)*)
        rest = ({ $($then:tt)* } else { $($else:tt)* })
    } => {
        println!("predicate: {}", stringify!($($predicate)*));
        println!("then: {}", stringify!($($then)*));
        println!("else: {}", stringify!($($else)*));
    };

    {
        predicate = ($($predicate:tt)*)
        rest = ($next:tt $($rest:tt)*)
    } => {
        branch_parser! {
            predicate = ($($predicate)* $next)
            rest = ($($rest)*)
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    branch! {
        if foo == bar {
            1
        } else {
            2
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
predicate: foo == bar
then: 1
else: 2
```

Comment: Awesome! Just a note, it also works without `predicate =` or `rest =` in the pattern. The parenthesis afterwards are what really matter.